# Como utilizar ajax/response para llenar tabla html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

Tengo una tabla en una Vista llamada **todas_calls_view.php** la cual la manda llamar el siguiente controlador **reg_calls_controller.php** y a la función **todas_calls_view**. Como pueden ver cuando manda llamar la vista también le pasa un parámetro con datos($data).

#### Controlador `reg_calls_controller => función`

```php
   public function todas_calls() {
     
     $sess_array = array(
       'id_user' => $this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_user'],
       'username' => $this->session->userdata['sess_data']['username']
     );
   
     $data = array();
     $data['sess_data'] = $sess_array;
   
     $date_inicio = "2018-01-01 00:00:00";
     $date_fin = "2018-01-31 23:59:59";
   
     $data['todas_calls']  = $this->reg_calls_model->todas_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin);
   
     $data['menu_higher'] = $this->load->view('elementos/menu_higher_view.php', $data, TRUE);
     $data['menu_left'] = $this->load->view('elementos/menu_left_view.php', '', TRUE);
   
     $this->load->view("todas_calls_view.php", $data);
   
   }
```

Entonces estoy intentando hacer es que en esa vista tengo dos inputs donde capturo dos fechas, después un botón llama a una función JavaScript y este java script llama a la mismo controlador de arriba  pero a otra función llamada **filtrar_calls** y ya obtengo los datos en el success, pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es pasárselos a la tabla.

#### JavaScript

```
function accion_botones(accion) {
            var url;
            if (accion = 1) {
                url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/filtrar_calls')?>";
            } else if (accion = 2) {
                url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/export_pdf_calls')?>";
            } else {
                url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/export_excel_calls')?>";
            }

            var date_inicio = document.getElementById('date_inicio').value;
            var date_fin = document.getElementById('date_fin').value; 

            $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {'date_inicio':date_inicio, 'date_fin':date_fin},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('muy bien!');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error...');
            }
        }); 
        }
```

#### Tabla que quiero llenar con los datos que tengo en el succes dej JS

```
   <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Origen</th>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Grupo</th>
         <th>Destino</th>
         <th>Seg.</th>
         <th>Min.</th>
         <th>Fecha</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <?php if($todas_calls != NULL) : ?>  
               <?php foreach($todas_calls as $row) : ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row->calldate;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->clid;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->src;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->dst;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->dcontext;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->channel;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->dstchannel;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->lastapp;?></td>
           </tr>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
           <?php endif; ?>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer de esta forma: recorrer el Array mediante un **for** para luego imprimir en **tbody** de la tabla.

```html
   <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Origen</th>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Grupo</th>
         <th>Destino</th>
         <th>Seg.</th>
         <th>Min.</th>
         <th>Fecha</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="DataResult"> // Id de la tbody
       
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

esta seria la funcion para imprimir la data dentro del **tbody**

```js
   function accion_botones(accion) {
     var url;
     if (accion = 1) {
       url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/filtrar_calls') ?>";
     } else if (accion = 2) {
       url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/export_pdf_calls') ?>";
     } else {
       url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/export_excel_calls') ?>";
     }

     var date_inicio = document.getElementById('date_inicio').value;
     var date_fin = document.getElementById('date_fin').value;

     $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       data: {
         'date_inicio': date_inicio,
         'date_fin': date_fin
       },
       dataType: "JSON",
       success: function(data) {
         var html = '';
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           html += '<tr>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].calldate + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].clid + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].src + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].dst + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].dcontext + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].channel + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].dstchannel + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + data[i].lastapp + '</td>' +
             '</tr>';
         }
         $('#DataResult').html(html);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert('Error...');
       }
     });
   }
```

Comment: Pero yo tengo codigo en el tbody si checas, esa es como mi duda.

Comment: No afecta que yo ya tenga codigo php en tbody?

Comment: para eso deberias de usar un codigo que permita destruir la tabla y que inicie solo cuaundo usted envie ciertos parametros a tu funcion podrias usar la siguiente **$("#DataResult").dataTable().fnDestroy();**

Comment: @Javierfr no se que tan avansado vayas en code igniter: pero en General PHP solo se ejecuta de lado de servidor; todo eso que haces se arma de lado del servidor; viaja por la red/internet y es mostrado en codigo html en la ventana del navegador.

Comment: @Javierfr si quieres modificar algo que ya esta en pantalla entonces tienes que usar Javascript como lenguaje y que este se comunique con tu php para que el javascript reciba la informacion y la manipule para agregar, modificar o actualizar tu datos en pantalla.

Comment: @Javierfr si la informacion que agregas a la pantalla esta asociada a plugins es importante que controles el flujo de inicializacion y destrucción cada vez que agregues contenido incluso hay pluggin que permiten agregar elementos mediante sus propios métodos sin necesidad de destruirlo y re-inicializarlos.

Comment: @RCA no tiene sentido agregar sniped a un codigo que no se ejecutar utiliza el marcado de código ( ``` ) al inicio y al final